# Can I use trick granting items to learn the 2nd 'attack' trick?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, animals

Expanding from [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64653/do-magic-items-granting-an-animal-extra-tricks-stack-with-already-known-tricks) question, if I use a Bridle of Tricks or War Saddle to give my mount/animal friend the 'attack' trick, and I then use one of its normal trick slots to teach it the 2nd 'attack' trick (see [Handle Animals](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/handle-animal)), allowing it to attack undead etc?

Edit: Can I load the Bridle of Tricks with the 2nd attack, so when I put it on an animal that already knows attack it will work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Technically, *training* an animal to attack anything takes twice as long, but that trick is *still* only one trick...

The [attack trick](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/handle-animal) says that

> Teaching an animal to attack all creatures (including such unnatural creatures as undead and aberrations) counts as two tricks.

*Read that carefully!* Only for *teaching* the animal the—let's call it—*attack anything* trick does the attack anything trick count as two tricks. For all *other* purposes (e.g. computing how many tricks an animal can have, how many tricks an appropriate magic item can grant) the attack anything trick is but *one* trick. To be clear, the skill [Handle Animal](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/handle-animal) on Common Tricks says

> The following tricks can be taught to animals by training the animal for a week and making a successful Handle Animal skill check against the listed DC.

Because the attack anything trick counts as two tricks while the handler's teaching it, the handler takes 1 week and a successful Handle Animal skill check (DC 20) then *another* week and a successful Handle Animal skill check (DC 20). If both skill checks are successful, the handler's taught the animal the attack anything trick. For all other purposes, the attack anything trick counts as one trick.

#### "That sounds a little shady..."

While this *really is* what the rules *say*, I, too, for example, have just written down on my character sheet that my inquisitor's attack bird had the attack trick twice and counted it as two of the bird's tricks. Things *are* easier that way, and nobody'll fight you if you do that. But doing that causes some problems.

The game has no mechanism for *adding* the attack anything trick *to* the animal's already learned attack trick. Further, once an animal's learned a trick there's no readily available way to cause the animal to *unlearn* that trick.

So while it *seems* shady to have the attack anything trick be *taught* as two tricks but *learned* as one trick, under this technical reading, an animal that's *already* learned the attack trick can learn the attack anything trick and those tricks together occupy two tricks the animal can learn. But were the GM to mandate that the attack anything trick counts as *two* tricks the animal's learned (rather than two tricks the handler's *teaching*), an animal that already know the attack trick would be forced to spend *three* of its precious tricks to do the same, one on the attack trick and two *more* on the attack anything trick.

### ...But you've proposed reasonable house rules

What would be awesome *and* reasonable is if the attack trick said that a trainer could teach an animal that's *already* learned the attack trick the attack anything trick as a lone trick, perhaps taking twice as long to teach. I mean, really, that's how it *should* work. Unfortunately, the game doesn't say that, but the GM could rule that's how it works.

So, assuming the DM instead counts the attack anything trick as a different but improved version of the attack trick counting as its own lone trick (perhaps treating the attack trick similar to a feat's prerequisite for the attack anything trick), adding *only* that second trick *after* an animal's learned the attack trick is a reasonable house rule no matter how that second attack trick's added (e.g. magic items, teaching).

Comment: Good answer. I'm still not 100% sure of your reasoning that it is only 1 trick, but I can see how you got there. It says "teaching it ... counts as 2 tricks", it never says it counts as 2 during the teaching process. Another interpretation (that I assumed) is that the animal can learn 6 tricks. Teaching it attack anything counts as 2 tricks, so it can now learn 4 other tricks. This comes from the fact that the trick limit is on how many tricks an animal can learn, not how many it has (as seen in the linked question). One could conceive of animals with innate tricks, like spider spinning a web.

Comment: @GreySage *Teaching* it counts as two tricks. *Learning* it doesn't. `:-)`

Comment: There's a very fine line between those in my opinion. It's true they could have said "Learning attack anything counts as 2 tricks" if they meant it to cost 2.

Comment: I suppose in the end it doesn't matter, since by abusing magic items you can give an animal 6+5+6 tricks, +/-1 doesn't impact much.

Comment: @GreySage ...And unless you want the creature doing something wacky during combat you can always "push" the poor creature.

Comment: My endgame is riding a giant Chameleon into battle, having it steal stuff with its 15ft reach tongue, and hiding behind it when I want to be stealthy, in case you were curious.